# XML Transformation - move childNode to another parentNode if hit maximum occurrence

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing the XML-XML transformation using java (via .xsl). Currently, I have a difficulty to limit maximum occurrence of a node and move the rest to another parentNode.

For example:
I have a XML as below

```
<room>
    <box>
        <ball>1</ball>
        <ball>2</ball>
        <ball>3</ball>
        <ball>4</ball>
        <ball>5</ball>
        <ball>6</ball>
        <ball>7</ball>
    </box>
</room>
```

Then, I need to transform to XML that only allow maximum of 3 occurrence per "box" element. If it exceeds 3, new parentNode of "box" will be created, then put next 3 "ball" element into it.

My desired output of XML transformation would be as below:

```
<room>
    <box>
        <ball>1</ball>
        <ball>2</ball>
        <ball>3</ball>
    </box>
    <box>
        <ball>4</ball>
        <ball>5</ball>
        <ball>6</ball>
    </box>
    <box>
        <ball>7</ball>
    </box>
</room>
```

I am appreciated if anyone can guide me on how can I create a XSL stylesheet for this rule.

Answer (score 2):

An easy XSLT-1.0 solution is using the following templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/room">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="box/ball[position() mod 3 = 1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ball">
    <box>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ball[1]" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ball[2]" />
    </box>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite give the expected output. Because you don't have a template matching the `ball` elements in the other positions, XSLT's built-in template will be used, which will then output any text nodes within them. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpR for example.....

Comment: Which can be corrected by moving the condition `[position() mod 3 = 1]` to `apply-templates` line.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2/3 this can be solved with positional grouping `<xsl:for-each-group select="ball" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $size">` e.g. with XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="size" as="xs:integer" select="3"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="box">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ball" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $size">
          <xsl:copy select="..">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZA

Comment: Thanks Martin, it is working and I choose to use XLST 3.0